# How does $\log(x^2 + 1)$ become $\log(2x^2)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

My textbook attempts to take the big O of $\log(x^2 +1)$. It proceeds by saying $x^2 + 1 \le 2x^2$ when $x \ge 1$. But I don't know how it came up with this idea.

Question:

Why set $x^2+1$ to a random value to be $2x^2$? Why $2$ of all numbers? Why not $x^2$ or $x^3$?

Comment: $\log (a+1)$ is hard to deal with, but $\log(2a)$ is easy to deal with? You can certainly say that $1+x^2< \alpha x^2$ for any $\alpha>1$, if $x$ is large enough. But since you are taking logs, $\log (\alpha x^2)=\log\alpha + 2\log x$ and $2\log x$ dominates any constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We’re not setting $x^2+1$ to anything. We want to find an upper bound on $\log(x^2+1)$ that can be expressed as a fairly simple function of $x$. Provided that $x\ge 1$, we know that $x^2+1\le 2x^2$, so $\log(x^2+1)\le\log(2x^2)$, and $\log(2x^2)$ can be expressed as a simple function of $\log x$:

$$\log(2x^2)=\log 2+2\log x\;.$$

If $x\ge 2$, we know that $\log x\ge\log 2$, and therefore

$$\log(x^2+1)\le\log 2+2\log x\le 3\log x\;.$$

This is exactly the kind of thing that’s needed in order for us to conclude that $\log(x^2+1)$ is $O(\log x)$: we have constants $M$ and $c>0$ such that

$$\log(x^2+1)\le c\log x$$

for all $x\ge M$. Specifically, we can use $M=2$ and $c=3$.

We couldn’t have used $x^2$, because $x^2+1$ **isn’t** less than or equal to $x^2$. We could have used $x^3$: $x^2+1\le x^3$ for $x\ge 2$, say, so

$$\log(x^2+1)\le\log x^3=3\log x$$

for $x\ge 2$, and again we’ve shown that $\log(x^2+1)$ is $O(\log x)$.

We could have used $5x^2$: $x^2+1\le 5x^2$ for $x\ge 1$, so

$$\log(x^2+1)\le\log(5x^2)=\log 5+2\log x\;.$$

And $\log 5+2\log x\le3\log x$ for $x\ge 5$, so $\log(x^2+1)\le3\log x$ for $x\ge 5$, and again we’ve shown that $\log(x^2+1)$ is in $O(\log x)$.

Comment: Okay so you took the log of both sides...but how did log2$x^2$ = log2 + 2logx? What method did you use?

Comment: @user983246: Just basic facts about logs: $\log(xy)=\log x+\log y$, and $\log x^a=a\log x$.

Comment: but using that fact : log2$x^2$ = log 2 + log$x^2$

Comment: @user983246: And $\log x^2=2\log x$.

Comment: Oh I see. Nice catch. I never understood when you could put the exponent in front...

Comment: @user983246: You always have $\log x^a=a\log x$, even when the exponent isn’t a positive integer.

Answer (score 3):

I can give some observations.

- My guess for changing $x^2+1$ to $2x^2$ is to get rid of the $+1$ and get a monomial (one term) so that taking the log is easier.
- $x^3$ would not be good because it is asymptotically too fast compared to $x^2+1$. Try following the textbook using $x^3$ instead of $2x^2$ and you'll get <s>an upper bound (big-O notation) that is looser (bigger) than the one produced by $2x^2$ and therefore gives less information about the growth of $\log(x^2+1)$.</s> Edit: the big-O notation result will be the same if you use $x^3$, but all the inequalities before applying big-O will be looser. In this example it doesn't matter, but usually you want to bound things more tightly/closely rather than loosely.
- The coefficient $2$ is arbitrary. You could use $1.000000001 x^2$ instead for a slightly tighter bound! Anything $>1$ is ok.

Comment: @user157227 My mistake, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

You could have taken $3 x^2$ if you wanted, or $x^3$.  You'd end up with the same result.
But not $x^2$: it's certainly not true that $x^2 + 1 \le x^2$.